# Checking IDs with Selenium & Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am running a selenium test with python. I am having a specific problem with the following bit of html code.....

```
<span class="cke_label" id="cke_8_label">Source</span>
```

I have tried the following.......

```
self.assert_element_present_by_class('Source button', 'cke_8_label', 'cke_label')**
```

here's the function .........

```
def assert_element_present_by_class(self, description, id, name):
    sel = self.selenium
    try:
        self.assert_(sel.is_element_present("//" + id + "[contains(@class,'" + name + "')]"))
        logging.info('PASS: "' + description + '" is present')
    except Exception:
        logging.exception('FAIL: "' + description + '" is not present')
```

This gives me this error.......

> File "Template_Designer_P37.py", line 293, in
>   assert_element_present_by_class
>       self.assert_(sel.is_element_present("//" + id + "[contains(@class,'" + name + "')]"))   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 420, in assertTrue
>       raise self.failureException(msg) AssertionError: False is not true

I have tried a couple of other methods, such as simply trying to assert that the id **strong text**exists

My hunch is that the problem surrounds the 'id'

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try this: `self.assert_(self.sel.is_element_present("//*[@id='" + id + "' and contains(@class,'" + name + "')]"))`

Answer (score 2):

You try to use incorrect xpath and insert id instead of tag name. So correct version will be

```
self.assert_(sel.is_element_present("//*[@id='" + id + "' and contains(@class,'" + name + "')]"))
```

Comment: I think `self.sel` would do the task.